# why is the delete option missing from just one category?

Tags: categories, wp-admin, customization, admin-ui

A site I'm working on had one big category called `News`. I wanted to be a little more specific and create `Industry News` and `Company News`. Not a big deal at all, but when I go to delete `News`, I saw that delete options are missing! Both the checkbox...

[image: in the markup, there is a non-breaking space entity instead of a checkbox!]

...and the link that appears when you hover are just not there.

[image: where is that link?!]

I know I can delete this category directly from the database, so this is more for curiosity than anything...but what could make these options disappear for *just one category*?

Comment: any reason for the down vote...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're unable to delete just one category because it's your default category. You may change the default category via via **wp-admin > Settings > Writing > "Default Post Category"** .

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks for the answer, though, because searching for the question didn't really get me anywhere. In other words, it's not really 'missing.'